# How can I POST form data to ASP.NET WebAPI 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm having trouble accessing parameters submitted via POST in my ASP.NET WebAPI 2 application. I hav a very trivial controller and an action, which simply captures the parameter and returns 200.

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] string foo)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

And I'm making the request via cURL

```
curl http://localhost:24196/api/checkpoints -XPOST -d foo=bar
```

The parameter ends up being `null`. The same happens when I try this with jQuery.

```
$.post("http://localhost:24196/api/checkpoints", { foo: "bar" })
```

[I've found a post that seems to describe this issue](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/), but I'm not sure if that's really the correct way to fix this (using the `=` encoding).

What is the correct/standard way of talking to a WebAPI service, and how does the parameter binding actually work in these cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in the link, `FromBody` expects data in a certain way `=foo` - re: there is no "key". So:

Curl:

```
curl -X POST -d "=bar" http://localhost/controller
```

Jquery:

```
var _data = { "": "bar" };
```

---

Update:

Reference for this behavior: [Sending simple types](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data,-part-1#sending_simple_types)

> By default, Web API tries to get simple types from the request URI. The **FromBody** attribute tells Web API to read the value from the request body.
>
> ...If you need to get multiple values from the request body, define a complex type.
>
> Second, the client needs to send the value with the following format:
>
> =value

Hth...

Comment: How would the content be encoded if it wasnt just a string, but a structure? Also, where can I find documentation on this? I cant seem to google anything reasonable.

Comment: @JakubArnold it's specific to `FromBody` (aka "simple type") - updated with link reference - Hth...